# What should we try: low or high learning rate?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am tuning the learning rate for SGD and Adam. I will try with SGD first. I have a question about learning rate selection. What should I try first: low learning or high learning rate? I read some references that suggest to try with high learning rate and then reduce it by scheduling. Is it right? 
For Adam, it is an adaptive learning rate. Is it right that the learning rate of Adam method often less than 5 or 10 times than SGD learning rate?

Comment: Depends on your data set. You can choose a right learning rate using cross validation.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is time-consuming. I have 5 subjects in training set. I will use 4 subjects for training and 1 subject for validation. Don't worry about limited data-set because this is my task. I will use cross validation by randomly pick up 1 subject for validation, 4 remaining subjects for training and select a learning rate. For each time, I must spend 1 day to complete it. Hence, for 4 times cross validation, I must spend about 4 days. And change learning rate again. Do you have any tip for cross validation?

Answer (score 0):

The learning rate depends on your data and your problem. However, the Adam optimizer is typically considered a more advance optimizer because it tunes the learning rate as it trains. Tuning the learning rate as you train gives you the advantage of not getting stuck at a local optimum as well as not developing a bias towards certain kinds of data in your training set. I'm not sure what library you are using but regardless, plotting your training and validation would be worthwhile in visualizing your loss to get a better idea of whats happening. If for example you are using Keras this is quite easy...

```
# Record the Keras history object for plotting
keras_history_object = model.fit_generator(batch_generator(training_data, batch_size),
                                            steps_per_epoch=(len(training_data) * 3) / batch_size,
                                            epochs=epochs,
                                            verbose=1,
                                            validation_data=batch_generator(validation_data, batch_size),
                                            validation_steps=(len(validation_data) * 3) / batch_size)


# Plot the training and validation losses for visualization of this session
plt.figure(1, figsize=(25, 15))
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(keras_history_object.history['loss'])
plt.plot(keras_history_object.history['val_loss'])
plt.title(loss)
plt.ylabel(loss)
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Training set', 'Validation set'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]